# how to get Arabic Month Names in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying hard to get the 12 months names in Arabic , I tried a lot but nothing work.
any help ?

Comment: `I tried a lot but nothing work` <= can you post what you tried so far? Also why not leave as actual date/time types and let the presentation layer worry about how they are formatted at display time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save Hijri dates in sql server tables? What type of column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752319/how-to-save-hijri-dates-in-sql-server-tables-what-type-of-column)

Comment: Use Format thats returns a nvarchar value formatted with a specific format and include the culture for month names in arabic

Comment: Really Stupid People -_- , thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

I apologise if my spelling is incorrect:
I've made the assumption that you are selecting results from a table with either a date or datetime field.

```
select
    case (datepart(month, *DateField*))
    when 1 then N'Muḥarram'
    when 2 then N'Ṣafar'
    when 3 then N'Rabī‘ al-awwal'
    when 4 then N'Rabī‘ ath-thānī'
    when 5 then N'Jumādá al-ūlá'
    when 6 then N'Jumādá al-ākhirah'
    when 7 then N'Rajab'
    when 8 then N'Sha‘bān'
    when 9 then N'Ramaḍān'
    when 10 then N'Shawwāl'
    when 11 then N'Dhū al-Qa‘dah'
    when 12 then N'Dhū al-Ḥijjah'
    end
from *Table*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN CMonth=1 THEN N'يناير' 
      WHEN CMonth=2 THEN N'فبراير' 
      WHEN CMonth=3 THEN N'مارس' 
      WHEN CMonth=4 THEN N'ابريل' 
      WHEN CMonth=5 THEN N'مايو' 
      WHEN CMonth=6 THEN N'يونيو' 
      WHEN CMonth=7 THEN N'يوليو' 
      WHEN CMonth=8 THEN N'أغسطس' 
      WHEN CMonth=9 THEN N'سبتمبر' 
      WHEN CMonth=10 THEN N'أكتوبر' 
      WHEN CMonth=11 THEN N'نوفمبر' 
      WHEN CMonth=12 THEN N'ديسمبر' END
```

-_-

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMMM', 'ar-eg') AS arabic_Month_Name
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMMM yyyy', 'ar-eg') AS arabic_Month_Name_With_Year
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'ar-eg') AS arabic_Month_Name_Date
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.