# How to get the average dates between sales for each customer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find the average date between the sales in Sales Header Table :

```
select ID
      ,SaleNo
      ,ExitRef
      ,SaleDate
      ,TotalAmount
      ,UserRef
      ,AccYear
      ,DCRef
      ,CustRef
      ,DealerRef from sle.tblSaleHdr 
where AccYear=1402 
and saledate between '1402/01/01' and  '1402/06/30' 
and exitref is not null
and custref =200000499;
```

The Output data:

```
      ID    SaleNo  ExitRef SaleDate    TotalAmount UserRef AccYear DCRef   CustRef DealerRef
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
200891747   58565   200054893   1402/06/06  2503500.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200888868   55790   200054799   1402/05/30  2568000.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200883846   50824   200054611   1402/05/16  2691000.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200894862   61447   200055029   1402/06/13  2762989.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200886247   53211   200054706   1402/05/23  2896500.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200842910   12972   200053272   1402/02/11  3156296.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200864788   32263   200053969   1402/03/29  3662750.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200839963   10034   200053168   1402/02/04  4025000.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200850992   19058   200053479   1402/02/26  4025000.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200832007   2092    200052886   1402/01/14  4085121.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200899821   66220   200055260   1402/06/27  4417200.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200878505   45610   200054430   1402/05/02  4741550.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200870296   37619   200054152   1402/04/12  5618750.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200856484   24047   200053682   1402/03/08  6047750.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200881114   48183   200054514   1402/05/09  6551600.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200875681   42885   200054323   1402/04/26  6753182.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200837144   7221    200053053   1402/01/28  7457400.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200897329   63841   200055141   1402/06/20  8032500.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200873008   40254   200054238   1402/04/19  9187800.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200834587   4664    200052969   1402/01/21  9578392.00  157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200867534   34932   200054058   1402/04/05  10821692.00 157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200859185   26745   200053779   1402/03/15  10860292.00 157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200853617   21180   200053579   1402/03/01  11208792.00 157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200846720   15759   200053358   1402/02/18  11526000.00 157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200861967   29514   200053882   1402/03/22  14190400.00 157 1402    1   200000499   2572
200830603   688 200052825   1402/01/07  14547768.00 157 1402    1   200000499   2572
```

The Code is not working:

```
SELECT CustRef, AVG(DATEDIFF(day, LagSaleDate, SaleDate)) AS AverageDaysOfSales
FROM (
    SELECT CustRef, SaleDate, 
           LAG(SaleDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustRef ORDER BY SaleDate) AS LagSaleDate
    FROM SLE.tblSaleHdr
) AS SalesData
WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN '1402/01/01' AND '1402/06/30'
GROUP BY CustRef;
```

The error was:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 32 Conversion failed when converting
> date and/or time from character string.

The Saledate is Shamsi  and I use a function to convert it to Gregorian but result was null:

```
SELECT CustRef, AVG(DATEDIFF(day, gnr.solartodatetime(LagSaleDate), gnr.solartodatetime(SaleDate))) AS AverageDaysOfSales
FROM (
    SELECT CustRef, SaleDate, 
           LAG(gnr.solartodatetime(SaleDate)) OVER (PARTITION BY CustRef ORDER BY SaleDate) AS LagSaleDate
    FROM SLE.tblSaleHdr
) AS SalesData
WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN '1402/01/01' and  '1402/06/30' 
GROUP BY CustRef
```

Result:

```
custref    AverageDaysOfSales
     6    NULL
     9    NULL
    2000    NULL
    :
```

Comment: Hmmm in 1402 Castile conquered the Canary Islands, is that the year you meant? Either way, use an unambiguous date format such as `'14020101'` and probably also explicitly convert to `datetime2` or `date`.

Comment: @Charlieface I am in Iran and the Dates have over 600 years difference.  we are in the 1402 Solar /Shamshi Year.

Comment: As I suspected. But SQL Server doesn't support Hijri dates. You would need to store it in some other format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752319/how-to-save-hijri-dates-in-sql-server-tables-what-type-of-column You are probably best off storing it as normal Gregorian dates and converting afterwards.

Comment: @Charlieface, Unfortunately, I cannot store it in another format over a decade records have been stored in that way. Also, the sales and distribution program works in that format. Seems What I need, should be done in code run time.

Comment: Aside: If you do find a suitable function to convert the dates from Shamsi to Gregorian you can add [computed columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16) to the table to provide convenient access to the converted values. They can also be indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: This answer has been significantly revised from the original post that used `CONVERT(,,131)`. That conversion did not reflect the correct calendar.*

The date calculations require conversion of the Iranian/Persian/Shamsi  dates into SQL (Gregorian) dates. This can be done using in `CROSS APPLY` that converts the date using `PARSE(S.SaleDate AS DATE USING 'fa')`. That value can then be used in later calculations.

```
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT PARSE(S.SaleDate AS DATE USING 'fa') AS GDate
) DT
```

Merging the above logic into the original posted query yields something like:

```
SELECT CustRef, AVG(DATEDIFF(day, LagGDate, GDate)) AS AverageDaysOfSales
FROM (
    SELECT S.CustRef, S.SaleDate, DT.GDate,
           LAG(DT.GDate) OVER (PARTITION BY S.CustRef ORDER BY S.SaleDate) AS LagGDate
    FROM tblSaleHdr S
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT PARSE(S.SaleDate AS DATE USING 'fa') AS GDate
    ) DT
) AS SalesData
WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN '1402/01/01' AND '1402/06/30'
GROUP BY CustRef;
```

The results are:

| CustRef | AverageDaysOfSales |
| --- | --- |
| 200000499 | 7 |

Adding a `+ 0.0` after the `DATEDIFF()` will convert the value to a float, yielding a more precise result `7.000000`. (It appears that the given test data just happens to yield a round number.)

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WynU6yZs) that demonstrates the above and also shows some intermediate results.

Comment: I have revised the above answer to use `PARSE(value AS DATE USING 'fa')` which seems to produce the correct calendar conversion. My original post used `CONVERT(DATE, ..., 131)` which appears to use the [Tabular Islamic (AH) calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Islamic_calendar) instead of the needed [Solar Hijri (SH) calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Hijri_calendar). (I think I have those references right.)

Comment: Dear @t-n, I @.ppreciated for your pay attention, really interested.